# POV: you're on a losing streak

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Team Secret
> Replying to Elon Musk:
> POV: you're on a losing streak
> Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1459480404600176646)

Does "POV: you're on a losing streak" mean  "Persistence of Vision: You're suffering a series of losses"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"You're on a [losing streak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Losing_streak)" does mean "you're suffering a series of losses."

Here "POV" stands for "point of view." For more information, see the Know Your Meme entry for [POV Roleplays](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/pov-roleplays).

The Twitter user is responding to Elon Musk and saying, *this [what Musk said] is something **you the reader** would say/do if you were on a losing streak.* In other words, they are saying that Musk actually is on a losing streak.